# Row is not added into the database

Tags: python, mysql, import

I am using python to add a record into database. Below is my code, the code does not throw any exception and doesn't show any errors. But my insert query does not add any records into the database.I verified database connection by printing the mysql version.

```
import MySQLdb
import datetime

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","pass","selvapractice" )

cursor = db.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO setting(username,password,name,settings_createddate,settings_modifieddate) \
       VALUES ('Mac', 'Mohan', 'selva', datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime.now())"
try:
   cursor.execute(sql)
   db.commit()
except: 
   db.rollback()

db.close()
```

Any Help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure it's not throwing an exception that you're silently catching?  Add a `print()` in your `except` block: `except Exception as e: print(e)`

Comment: yes exception block prints hello.                               except:
   print "hello"
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   db.rollback()

Comment: how to find which type of exception?

Comment: I edited my original comment with code that will print the actual exception that's being raised.

Comment: Removed the SQL Server tag, because MySQLdb is an interface to MySQL.

Comment: @jedwards, nothing prints in console

Comment: By the way, it's likely because of this part: `datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime.now())"`

Comment: Is their any other way to add a timestamp in mysql using python?

Comment: @jedwards,getting format error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
import MySQLdb
import datetime

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","pass","selvapractice" )

cursor = db.cursor()

# If client and server times differ, and you want the client timestamp
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
sql = "INSERT INTO setting(username,password,name,settings_createddate,settings_modifieddate) \
       VALUES ('Mac', 'Mohan', 'selva', %s, %s)"  % (now, now)

# If they differ and you want the server timestamp
#   (or if you don't care and want the server timestamp anyway)
sql = "INSERT INTO setting(username,password,name,settings_createddate,settings_modifieddate) \
       VALUES ('Mac', 'Mohan', 'selva', NOW(), NOW())"
try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
except: 
    db.rollback()
    raise
finally:
    db.close()
```

Note that the query (`sql`) is a bit different.  The `datetime` stuff is pulled out of the string itself and placed after.  See [String Formatting Operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

I'm also re-raising the database exception, so you can see what it is and put `db.close()` in a `finally` block.

Lastly, this isn't the best way to do this either.  Some sort of PDO (maybe [Python Database Objects](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Python-Database-Objects-PDO/1.3.1)), or ORM (maybe [peewee](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) would be better.

Comment: the following error occurs Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sel.py", in <module>
    VALUES ('Mac', 'Mohan', 'selva', %d, %d)"  % (datetime.datetime.now
), datetime.datetime.now())
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not datetime.datetime

Comment: What is the field type of the last two columns (`settings_createddate`, `settings_modifieddate`)?

Comment: If you're not worried about timezone issues, you could simply make the second line of the query `VALUES ('Mac', 'Mohan', 'selva', NOW(), NOW())`

Comment: I just updated the code that should generate a timestamp-compatible  query.

Comment: ,please change this line to VALUES ('Mac', 'Mohan', 'selva', %s, %s)"  % (now, now) this one VALUES ('Mac', 'Mohan', 'selva',NOW(),NOW())".

Comment: @Madhesh, I added the one with the `NOW()` functions, but kept the other one.  Both have their own uses and each may be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Specify variables using %s or %(name)s parameter style

```
sql = "INSERT INTO setting(username,password,name,settings_createddate,settings_modifieddate) \
   VALUES (%s, %s, %s %s, %s)"
try:
   args = ('Mac', 'Mohan', 'Mohan', datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime.now())
   cursor.execute(sql, args)
   db.commit()
```